# Copy data from one part of a userform to another automatically

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I am trying to work with an Excel form using VBA that I have customized (I found the original on the web).

I have two tabs: one is called `Planning-Deleted`, the other is called `Planning-Deleted Data`. All the data that I enter in the first tab is copied to the second tab when I press a command button called `Add to Database`.

Is it possible to skip the command button altogether and record the data entered in cell D5 and D6 directly in the second tab and clear these cells for the next records? I have no knowledge of programming and I would appreciate as much clarity and specificity as possible.

If more details are needed, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some trigger to cause the copy operation to happen, for example:
Using the 'Change' event, you can trigger some action any time some value is entered into a sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Sheet2.Range(Target.Address).Value = Target.Value

End Sub
```

This code will copy any data entered into the first sheet into the same cell on the second sheet. 'Target' in this case is the cell where data was entered.
I'm not sure if this what you want though, since you also want to clear the cells after the copy. Can you describe when the copy-and-erase should occur, if not from clicking a button?

Also, your question doesn't seem to match your question's title. Can you clarify a bit what you are trying to accomplish?